# Can't establish a WebRTC connection between browser and server with Django and aiortc: WinError 10051

Tags: django, webrtc, aiortc

I have created a simple `WebRTC` conference where multiple peers on the same network can open a web page and see each other/talk to each other. Each peer keeps track of its own pool of `RTCPeerConnections`, while `Django` handles authorization and `django-channels` handle signaling through `WebSockets`.

I also need to stream audio data to the server for analysis. I decided to add the server as another `WebRTC` peer. In order to do that, I used `aiortc` module and created a class `RTCPeer` that handles `RTCPeerConnections` and a class `RTCRoom` that spawns `RTCPeers` and keeps track of them. Both are connected to signaling: they can send messages through `channel layer`; any messages received by WebSockets consumer are forwarded to `RTCRoom.receive`.

When I try to connect a client to the server, I run into error 10051 multiple times. It looks like none of the pairs of gathered `ICECandidates` can provide connection. What could be wrong here?

```
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('172.18.108.97', 58214) -> ('109.120.16.131', 63420)) State.FROZEN -> State.IN_PROGRESS
DEBUG:aioice.ice:Connection(0) protocol(1) > ('109.120.16.131', 63420) Message(message_method=Method.BINDING, message_class=Class.REQUEST, transaction_id=b'\xcc)\xfb\x9c\xba\xc4!\xc0\x85P\x8fs')
DEBUG:aioice.ice:Connection(0) protocol(1) error_received([WinError 10051] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на сокете при отключенной сети)
...
INFO:aioice.ice:Connection(0) Check CandidatePair(('172.18.108.97', 58214) -> ('192.168.1.149', 63420)) State.IN_PROGRESS -> State.FAILED
```

Full log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v70SwZS2332sAoAfEbVHAJDRVJ0FVovg/view?usp=sharing

`RTCRoom` and `RTCPeer` (part of `consumers.py`)

```
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from aiortc import (
    RTCPeerConnection, 
    RTCConfiguration, 
    RTCIceServer, 
    )
from aiortc.rtcsessiondescription import RTCSessionDescription
from aiortc.sdp import candidate_from_sdp


class RTCRoom:
    def __init__(self, channel_name, room_group_name):
        self.channel_name = channel_name
        self.room_group_name = room_group_name
        self.username = 'server'
        self.channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        self.peer_pool = dict()
        self.default_content = {
                'username' : self.username,
                'channel' : self.channel_name,
            }

    async def send(self, message): 
        message.update(self.default_content)
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'send',
                'data': message,  
            }
        )  

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        content = json.loads(text_data)
        peer_username = content.get('username')
        receiver = content.get('receiver')
        
        if self.username == peer_username:
            return

        if receiver is not None and receiver != self.username:
            return

        if content.get('connection') == 'init':
            if self.peer_pool.get(peer_username) is not None:
                await self.peer_pool[peer_username].peer_connection.close()
            self.peer_pool[peer_username] = RTCPeer(peer_username, self.channel_name, self.room_group_name)
            await self.send(
                {
                    'receiver': peer_username,
                    'connection': 'accept'
                }
            )
            return

        await self.peer_pool[peer_username].handle_message(content)



class RTCPeer:
    def __init__(self, peer_username, channel_name, room_group_name):       
        self.peer_username = peer_username
        self.channel_name = channel_name
        self.room_group_name = room_group_name
        self.channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        self.making_offer = False
        self.ignore_offer = False
        self.arbitration_roll = 101
        self.polite = True
        self.default_content = {
                'username' : 'server',
                'channel' : self.channel_name,
            }

        self.peer_connection = RTCPeerConnection()

    async def send(self, message): 
        message.update(self.default_content)

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'send',
                'data': message,  
            }
        )

    async def handle_message(self, content):
        description = content.get('description')
        candidate = content.get('candidate')
        peer_arbitration_roll = content.get('arbitrationRoll')

        if peer_arbitration_roll:
            print(f"ServerPeer: Receiving arbitration roll from {self.peer_username}: {peer_arbitration_roll}")
            await self.send({
                'receiver': self.peer_username, 
                'arbitrationRoll': self.arbitration_roll
            })

        try:
            if description:
                description = RTCSessionDescription(
                    sdp=description.get("sdp"), 
                    type=description.get("type")
                )
                
                if description.type == "offer":
                    await self.peer_connection.setRemoteDescription(description)
                    await self.peer_connection.setLocalDescription(await self.peer_connection.createAnswer())
                    await self.send({ 
                        'receiver': self.peer_username,
                        'description': {
                            'type': self.peer_connection.localDescription.type,
                            'sdp' : self.peer_connection.localDescription.sdp,
                        }
                    })                
            
            elif candidate:
                rtc_ice_candidate = candidate_from_sdp(candidate.get('candidate').split(":", 1)[1])
                rtc_ice_candidate.sdpMid = candidate.get('sdpMid')
                rtc_ice_candidate.sdpMLineIndex = candidate.get('sdpMLineIndex')
                await self.peer_connection.addIceCandidate(rtc_ice_candidate)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception in connection with peer {self.peer_username}: {e}")
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, looks like something wrong with your network setup between peers.

I suggest you trying simple check if there's connectivity via UDP between the hosts.

Here is a good example of how to do it via netcat: https://serverfault.com/a/733921

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have decided to send raw audio as Websockets binary frames for now, which is not perfect - sometimes I get corrupted audio data, I guess it has to do with packets getting lost/out of order.

I don't know if netcat can help, after all, Django dev server does not connect to other peers even though they run on the same computer.